# How to draw circle using Google Maps SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am really confused with this issue.
I want to draw circle on google map in my iOS app.
In SDK help provide examples for polygons only.
Anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 8):

I have no idea why you are noted down because I have the same problem.
After many research, and the Saxon Druce's answer, I've seen the Circle on Android SDK but not in iOS.

--- EDIT ---

There are 2 solutions here :
[How to display a circle in GMSMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380441/how-to-display-a-circle-in-gmsmapview)

--- EDIT 2 ----

Since his version 1.2.1 (23 April 2013), Google Maps SDK for iOS count a GMSCircle in his Shapes.

Now you can draw like this :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D circleCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.35, -122.0);
GMSCircle *circ = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:circleCenter
                                         radius:1000];

circ.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.05];
circ.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
circ.strokeWidth = 5;
circ.map = mapView;
```

source [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/shapes#circles)

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately, I didn't find solution, so I draw polygon with large amount of vertexes. Still hope that Google integrate this functionality in next release of SDK

Comment: Since now google maps sdk for ios has circle class! https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/shapes?hl=ru

Comment: I still got the exception .... whenever comes to circ.map = mapView; and circ setMap: mapView . Wht should I check first ?

Comment: @RajuGujarati it's been a while since I touch to iOS (this question has 3 year) but you can maybe see [the official doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#circles)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the SDK doesn't support circles, but there is a feature request to add circles here:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4971

In the meantime you could maybe fake a circle by drawing a polyline, with several short segments?