# How do I display MKCircle in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

I am having issues displaying a Overlay in swift 3..updates have been made and i cannot seem to get it to display: in my view did load

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    mapView.delegate = self
    setup()

    //on tap creates annotation with reverse geocoded address
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.addAnnotation))
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.78494283, longitude: -122.39712273)
    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: coordinates, radius: 1000, identifier: "Folsem Office")
    self.mapView.add(MKCircle(center: coordinates, radius: 500))

    region.notifyOnEntry = true
    region.notifyOnExit = true

}
```

in my delegate method:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if let circle = overlay as? MKCircle {
        let renderer = MKOverlayRenderer.init(overlay: circle)
        return renderer
    }
    return MKOverlayRenderer()
}
```

answer posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/33293217/5988899 doesnt seem to work for me

Answer (score 1):

Replace `MKOverlayRenderer.init()` with `MKCircleRenderer()`