# How can create geofence in GMSMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmsmapview

I want to create and monitor Geofence using GMSMapview (GoogleMaps) in iOS objective c. But after doing R & D so far, I noticed that GMSMapView does not providing any APIs and Framework to implement Geofence in iOS, I can't believe in this. It's available in Android also. 
Based on my research, Geofence is possible to implement using CoreLocation. But I want to implement using GMSMapView.

Does GoogleMap provide Geofence for iOS Platform?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you'r searching this. https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial

Comment: @dahiya_boy I have checked this link but this is in swift, and I want to do it in objective c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geofences feature is a capability of `CLLocationManager` not `MKMapView` or `GMSMapView`, maps are designed only for showing data on, geofences are represented as a circle in `GMSMapView` is `GMSCircle`  and in `MKMapView` is `MKCircle`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a circle(geo-fence) on your map you can try `GMSCircle`.

```
// Circle on GMSMapView
GMSCircle *geoCircle = [[GMSCircle alloc] init];
geoCircle.radius = 130; // radius in meters
geoCircle.position = [your_location].coordinate;
geoCircle.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
geoCircle.strokeWidth = 2;
geoCircle.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
geoCircle.map = mapView;
```

Hope this helps. Please refer the 
[GMSCircle Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_circle)

[u2Fans answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380441/how-to-display-a-circle-in-gmsmapview)

Comment: Thanks, It's very useful to me.